# Representing an association table linking two models

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to the NodeJs universe and I am using Sequelize with PostgreSQL for an ExpressJs project. 
I am having some issues finding the proper way to represent an association table between two models. 
Here are my two tables :

'players':

- id
- firstname
- lastname
- year_of_birth
- skills
- login
- password
- created_at
- updated_at

'teams':

- id
- name
- created_at
- updated_at

And the association table 'team_players':

- id
- id_team
- id_player

Given some examples on internet, I tried the following syntax :

```
Player.belongsToMany(Team, {foreignKey: 'id_player', through: 'team_players'});
```

When I am trying to access the data through this association like this :

```
Player.findAll({ include :[{model: Team,foreignKey: 'id_team', through: 'team_players'}] })
. then(results)[...]
```

It is not working.

Here are the model definitions I've done.

**Player model definition :**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('../config/postgres');
const { sequelizeInstance } = require('../config/postgres');

const { Model } = Sequelize;
const Team = require('./Team');

class Player extends Model {}
Player.init({
  firstname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {isAlpha: true}
  },
  lastname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {isAlpha: true}
  },
  year_of_birth: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      min: 1950,
      max: 2019,
      isNumeric: true
    },
  },
  skills: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {isInt: true}
  },
  login: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: 
    {
      isAlphanumeric: true,
      unique: true
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {isAlphanumeric: true}
  },
},
{
  sequelize: sequelizeInstance,
  timestamps: true,
  modelName: 'player',
  tableName: 'players'
});

Player.belongsToMany(Team, {foreignKey: 'id_player', through: 'team_players'});

module.exports = Player;
```

**Team model definition :**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('../config/postgres');
const { sequelizeInstance } = require('../config/postgres');

const { Model } = Sequelize;
const Player = require('./Player');

class Team extends Model {}
Team.init({
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
},
{
  sequelize: sequelizeInstance,
  timestamps: true,
  modelName: 'team',
  tableName: 'teams'
});

module.exports = Team;
```

**Here is the error message :**

```
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent:
   { error: column teams->team_players.teamId does not exist
       at Connection.parseE (/home/nku/sources/.perso/pasanga/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (/home/nku/sources/.perso/pasanga/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/nku/sources/.perso/pasanga/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:17)
     name: 'error',
     length: 125,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42703',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: '776',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '3293',
     routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
     sql:
      'SELECT "player"."id", "player"."firstname", "player"."lastname", "player"."yob", "player"."skills", "player"."login", "player"."password", "player"."created_at", "player"."updated_at", "teams"."id" AS "teams.id", "teams"."name" AS "teams.name", "teams"."created_at" AS "teams.created_at", "teams"."updated_at" AS "teams.updated_at", "teams->team_players"."created_at" AS "teams.team_players.created_at", "teams->team_players"."updated_at" AS "teams.team_players.updated_at", "teams->team_players"."id_player" AS "teams.team_players.id_player", "teams->team_players"."teamId" AS "teams.team_players.teamId" FROM "players" AS "player" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "team_players" AS "teams->team_players" INNER JOIN "teams" AS "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "teams->team_players"."teamId") ON "player"."id" = "teams->team_players"."id_player";' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your association from Players-to-Team is OK.  I think you could solve the problem by renaming `team_players.id_team` to the default name `team_players.teamId`

Or, you could add an association from Team-to-Players in order to handle your chosen foreign key, with something like this:

`Team.belongsToMany (Player,{foreignKey: 'id_team', through: 'team_players'});`

**Edited June 5**

Here is some working code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const node_app_name = require("../sqltest");  // my db instance here
const { Model } = Sequelize;

class Player extends Model {}
Player.init({
  firstname: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastname: Sequelize.STRING,
},
{sequelize: node_app_name.sequelizeDB});

class Team extends Model {}
Team.init({
  name: Sequelize.STRING
},
{sequelize: node_app_name.sequelizeDB});

class TeamPlayer extends Model {}
TeamPlayer.init({
    id_team: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    id_player: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
{sequelize: node_app_name.sequelizeDB}); 

Player.belongsToMany(Team, {foreignKey: 'id_player', through: TeamPlayer});
Team.belongsToMany (Player,{foreignKey: 'id_team', through: TeamPlayer});

Player.findAll({    
    include: 
       [{
          model: Team,
          required: false
        }]
}).then(pat => {
   console.log(pat);
});
```

Hope this helps.  Note that the `belongsToMany()` associations occur **AFTER** both models are initialized.

Comment: I tried both tricks, it's not working for me. 
Moreover the line : 


Team.belongsToMany(Player,{foreignKey: 'id_team', through: 'team_players'});


Prompts me the following error: 

  throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
      ^

Error: team.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model



Do you have an idea of what could possibly trigger this error ?

Comment: Sounds to me like the new association cannot find Team (or Player).  Where do you have this code located?

Comment: The file is located in the same folder, and I have them "imported" with the require statement.

Comment: The association from team->player has to be done *after* the Player module exists. If that line of code is in the Team model, Player probably does not exist (you can test by debugging).  A simple way to verify - move the team->player code to immediately before your findAll() statement.

Comment: Still not working. 
I am wondering whether I am doing the database representation properly ?
Have you ever used an association table in Sequelize ?
How did you make it work please ?